# Anyone know of a utility to print a set of similar web pages?

Tags: printing, automation, bulk

I need to print potentially a couple of hundred letters (formatted web pages) which are automatically generated by another system.

I'm looking for something that I can **point at a directory containing these web pages**, **set the print options once** and then it will **print them all without any further intervention** or messing about.

Preferably free. Windows (XP onwards).

Comment: So, there's no web server involved, but you have direct access to the HTML source files in some directory on the file system? And do these have any references to other files (stylesheets, images)?

Comment: No - single HTML file for each page - no images - stylesheet included within the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up concatenating the HTML files into one:

```
type *.html > all.html
```

Then right-clicking `all.html` and printing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) (webkit based HTML-Rendering) to save the pages into an easily printable file, like PDF, and print that one using f.e. the Acrobat Reader with command line options.